# How to add node to existing XML Document

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm using stax to parse my document, here is a dummy example of my XML document :

```
<data>

<video>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</video>

<book id="1">
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

<book id="n">
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

//insert new node here

</data>
```

How can I insert node after nth book(where n is any number). THank you

Comment: I would use XSLT to add the node beforehand. Is this workable in your situation?

Comment: @mdma not really I'm trying to append this node as a part of the bigger picture something else is happening afterwords

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your [XMLEventReader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) from the factory with your own implementation that provides [your own events](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory.html) at the appropriate time. You might extend [EventReaderDelegate](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/EventReaderDelegate.html) to do this. You'd queue up the events you want to insert, count the elements read and provide them at the appropriate time.

*If you're using [XMLStreamReader](http://XMLStreamReader), the same principle applies but there's a few more methods to take care of.*

Comment: I don't really get what kind of events are you talking about I just want to insert node in the document, if it was at the end or at the begining of the file I'd turn it into string and append it but I have a node constraint after which I should insert another node. thank you for answering

Comment: @London - You would insert the nodes by returning events created from a `XMLEventFactory`. If you provide some sample code showing how you're using StAX, it would be easier to provide relevant guidance.